# MYSQL addition of rows that match dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have stock data with Open, High, Low, Close in a mysql DB.  I have multiple stocks & for some instances I'd like to create custom stock groups where add the open for the group, add the high, add the low and add the close to get a collective OHLC.

I've read that it is faster & more efficient to do math with SQL than PHP.  Is this an instance to simply do it in PHP?

Edit:  Sorry my original question was not clear.  So I'm looking for the query for how you would do it.  I've searched & I can't find a way to add the results.

The query I'm working with is a simple pull 1 ticker from the DB:

```
SELECT dates, ticker, open, high, low, close
FROM stocks
WHERE dates <= 2012-04-15
ORDER BY dates ASC
```

This is an example of the results

```
Date        Ticker    Open     High    Low     Close
04/15/12    BAC       9.25     9.38    9.04    9.10
04/15/12    F         11.98    11.99   11.45   11.30
04/16/12    BAC       9.10     9.25    9.03    8.78
04/16/12    F         11.30    11.75   11.03   11.60
```

I need a query that would add the following results into a single result looking like this:

```
Date        Ticker    Open     High    Low     Close
04/15/12    MYTICK    21.23    21.37   20.49   20.4
04/16/12    MYTICK    20.4     21      20.06   20.38
```

I hope this is more clear about what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: "Is this an instance to simply do it in PHP?" No. Why do you want to? Presumably you have a reason, otherwise you wouldn't be asking...

Comment: What are you currently doing (code example)?

Comment: I edited the original question with code so that it would be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    dates,
    SUM(open) AS open,
    SUM(high) AS high,
    SUM(low) AS low,
    SUM(close) AS close
FROM stocks
GROUP BY dates
ORDER BY dates ASC
```

I am not sure what you want for the "Ticker" column. You can add a `WHERE` clause to limit it to a particular date or date range.